# Panel Data Ordered Probit in Stata 12

Tags: stata

I am using Stata 12 and I have to run a Ordered Probit (oprobit) with a panel dataset. I know that "oprobit" command is compatible with cross-section analysis. In the new version of Stata (Stata 13) they have "xtoprobit" command to account for Random Effects Ordered Probit. I need the similar command for Stata 12. I have checked "reoprob" command but when I use it with my panel dataset I have the following error :

"factor variables and time-series operators not allowed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means you need to create your own dummy variables instead using the factor variable notation i.dummyvar. Try this:

```
tab dummyvar, gen(D)
reg y D*
```

This will creates a set of dummy variables (D1, D2,...) reflecting the observed values of the tabulated variable.

Some of the older user-written commands do not know what to do with the factor variable notation, which is convenient, but fairly new.

You can also explore `xi` for more complicated tasks.

Comment: +1. The user-written `reoprob` was last revised in 2001. Expecting it to support more recent developments such as factor variables is doomed to failure.